# Is there a way to extract two-dimensional array from nested dictionary, with its length being unknown

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to extract the two-dimensional array (output) from the multidimensional dictionary (input) with the unknown length, **every letter is the pointer to the next letter** (string IDs are represented by the capital letters). Hence I need to build a 2-dimensional array full of 1-dimensional IDs, which I can use to get the other data, keeping this "every current ID is the pointer to the next ID" type of a data chain.

```
Input: {A:[B,C], B:[D, E], C:[F], D:[], F:[R], E:[]}
Output: [[A,B,D], [A,B,E], [A,C,F,R]]

Schematics:
A->B->D->END; 
A->B->E->END;
A->C->F->R->END;
```

e.g.
"Room" -> "Shelf" -> "Book" -> "Paper"; "Lot" -> "Car" -> "Glove Compartment" -> "Candy"

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the first element in the input object will always be the starting point?

Comment: @JonWarren no, you can't assume that since objects don't preserve order.

Comment: @junvar Good point, but then I wonder why the example output only started at `A`? Maybe there's a starting point variable that was excluded from the example

Comment: @junvar Yes, there will be starting point, sorry forgot to explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let input = {A: ['B', 'C'], B: ['D', 'E'], C: ['F'], D: [], F: ['R'], E: []};
let start = 'A';

let x = k =>
    input[k] && input[k].length ? input[k].map(v => x(v).map(r => [k, ...r])).flat() : [[k]];

let output = x(start);
console.log(output); // [['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'F', 'R']];
```

Comment: If used strings (as IDs), the last ID is getting split by 1 letter. e.g. input: {'someID1':['someID2'], 'someID2':['someID3'], 'someID3': []};    output: 
 ["someID1", "someID2", "s", "o", "m", "e", "I", "D", "3"];